# Calculate an area under a curve with SAS

Tags: sas

I have 2 vectors $x=(1,2,3,4,5)$ and $y=(0,1,5,3,1)$ for example.
Is it possible to calculate the area under the curve $C_f$ ($f(x)=y$), using linear estimation for example, with SAS?

Comment: Do you have a formula or calculation engine for your function, or do you only have values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest solution is

## Trapezoidal integration

you actually sum up the surface of the pyramids under the piecewise linear function, just like Kodiologist does.

```
data x_y;
    input x y;
    datalines;
1 0
2 1
3 5
4 3
5 1
;
run;

data Trapezoidal;
    set x_y end=last;
    retain integral;
    lag_x=lag(x); lag_y = lag(y);
    if _N_ eq 1 then integral = 0;
    else integral = integral + (x - lag_x) * (y + lag_y) / 2;

    ** Comment the following statements to see the algorithm at work **;
    if last;
    drop lag_:;
run;
```

## Simpsons' parabolic rule

is applicable and more accurate if

- your x axis is equidistant (true in your case),
- you have an odd number of values  (true in your case) and
- function y is continuous and has a continuous derivative

See also [Simpsons' parabolic rule on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simpson%27s_rule)

```
data parabolic;
    set x_y end=last;
    base=dif(x);   
    if _N_ gt 2 and base ne lag(base) 
        then put 'ERROR: Simpsons rule does not apply for unequaly spaced x axes' / _all_;
    if last and not mod(_N_, 2) 
        then put 'ERROR: Simpsons rule does not apply for even number of values' / _all_;

    retain sum 0;
    if _N_ eq 1 or last then sum = sum + y;
    else if mod(_N_, 2) then sum = sum + 2 * y;
    else                     sum = sum + 4 * y;

    if last then integral = base * sum / 3;

    ** Comment the following statements to see the algorithm at work **;
    *if last;
    *keep integral;
run;
```

Comment: that's exactly what I needed.
Is it possible to program that if I have missing datas, for exemple
$\begin{matrix}
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\ 
1 & 2 & NA &0  & 1
\end{matrix}$ (trapezoidal integration is enough for me)

Comment: with `set x_y (where=(y ne .)) end=last;`, you interpolate linearly for missing values in the middle. Do you have missing values at the end points too?

Answer (score 1):

What curve? Do you mean the piecewise linear function with vertices at (1, 0), (2, 1), (3, 5), etc? If so, here's how an algorithm to do it in Python, which you can adapt to SAS.

```
import numpy as np

def piecewise_linear_auc(x, y):
    return np.sum(
        np.abs(np.diff(x)) * np.abs(np.diff(y)) / 2. +
        np.diff(x) * np.minimum(y[1:], y[:-1]))

print piecewise_linear_auc(
    x = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]),
    y = np.array([0, 1, 5, 3, 1]))
```

The idea is, for each pair of points, we multiply the x- and y-differences together and halve it, then add that to the x-difference times the lesser of the two y-coordiantes.